# How do I find the absolute position of all hyperlink elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offset

I would like to get the absolute position of all html hyperlink elements.
I write a jquery to find absolute position of each link element like the following:

```
jQuery('a').each(function() {
    var elLink = jQuery(this);
    console.log(this.text + ' => ' + this.href + ' ' + JSON.stringify(elLink.offset()) + ' top:' + elLink.css('top') + ' left:' + elLink.css('left'))
});
```

However, it doesn't work. 
For example, on page of http://www.actuino.fr, There is a link called "Le Crawler" will give me top = 0 and left = 0, while the "Contact" link give me the correct position. No all links are hidden.

So how could I get absolute position of these links? 
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `position()`

Comment: [`position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) gives *the current coordinates [...], relative to the offset parent.* and [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) gives *the current coordinates [...], relative to the document.*. Have you tried `elLink.css('top');` and `elLink.css('left');`?

Comment: `No all links are hidden.` is there any typo?

Comment: Did you wait for the page to load?

Comment: @ D4V1D : Update post with `elLink.css`.  `elLink.css('top');` and `elLink.css('left');` give me `auto`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there should be any issues regarding getting the `.offset()` of any element whether that is absolute,relative, fixed or static positioned.

But one thing to be noticed:

In the below example i have three anchors and one of them is hidden although that is absolutely positioned but top,left has been assigned to 0 by the browser.

```js
jQuery('a').each(function() {
    var elLink = jQuery(this);
    $(document.body).append('<pre>'+this.href + ':::<--href:::.offset():::-->' + JSON.stringify(elLink.offset()) +'</pre>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#123' style='margin:40px 0 0 80px;'>link 1</a>
<a href='#456' style='position:absolute; right:0; bottom:50px;'>link 2</a>
<a href='#789' style='display:none; position:absolute; left:0; bottom:50px;'>link 2</a>
```